# ASP.NET WEB API - Validation Attributes for Class Level never gets called if Property level Validation fails

Tags: asp.net-web-api

In MVC, Validation for Class Level Attributes never gets called if Property level Validation fails.

How to solve this problem? I want the error list for both property and Validation levels.

Comment: You question title says "ASP.NET Web API" and your question says "MVC". Which one?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it can be done with the existing architecture of either Web API or MVC framework.

Class validators will only run after all property validators pass, and this behavior is locked in a private `CompositeModelValidator` class.

See here (for Web API, but for MVC the class is almost identitcal):

```
private class CompositeModelValidator : ModelValidator
        {
            public CompositeModelValidator(IEnumerable<ModelValidatorProvider> validatorProviders)
                : base(validatorProviders)
            {
            }

            public override IEnumerable<ModelValidationResult> Validate(ModelMetadata metadata, object container)
            {
                bool propertiesValid = true;

                foreach (ModelMetadata propertyMetadata in metadata.Properties)
                {
                    foreach (ModelValidator propertyValidator in propertyMetadata.GetValidators(ValidatorProviders))
                    {
                        foreach (ModelValidationResult propertyResult in propertyValidator.Validate(metadata, container))
                        {
                            propertiesValid = false;
                            yield return new ModelValidationResult
                            {
                                MemberName = ModelBindingHelper.CreatePropertyModelName(propertyMetadata.PropertyName, propertyResult.MemberName),
                                Message = propertyResult.Message
                            };
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (propertiesValid) //<---- HERE
                {
                    foreach (ModelValidator typeValidator in metadata.GetValidators(ValidatorProviders))
                    {
                        foreach (ModelValidationResult typeResult in typeValidator.Validate(metadata, container))
                        {
                            yield return typeResult;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/Validation/ModelValidator.cs